# Inline tags in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm doing something like this:

```
{{someFlag ? "<b>Bold Text</b>" : "<i>Italic Text</i>"}}
```

But as everyone knows, things don't always go that smoothly. When I included a "tag" in the inline code, AngularJS seems to completely ignored the whole thing and rendered the source code.

I tried

```
"\<b>.....
```

and

```
"&lt;b>...
```

but they both didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Why not using ngClass ? Or ngBindHtml ?

Comment: @FlorianF. - Since I'm directly doing some calculation on the spot (and it's inside two ng repeat), I can't use ng bind html.

Comment: Yes you can, just call a function instead of an inline if ? It's probably not the best approach though and I would probably go with ngClass or a directive.

Comment: @FlorianF. It seems you were right, I can indeed use ng-bind-html and put the whole thing inside it. Other doing this, is there no way to create a tag with the `{{}}` syntax?

Comment: does {{{ instead of {{ not escape the html? (i know that's how mustache et al work...)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Added a specific detail about your comment in the answer.

Comment: Download `angular-sanitize.js` from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngSanitize . Then load this file after angularJs load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posted in the comments, you have a few options, from worse to better imho :

First is to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<div ng-bind-html="italicOrBold('With ngBindHtml', someFlag)"></div>

$scope.italicOrBold = function(text, bold){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(bold ? '<b>Test</b>' : '<i>Test</i>');
}
```

Second is to use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), which is not a too bad design

```
<div ng-class="{'text-bold' : someFlag, 'text-italic' : !someFlag}">With ngClass</div>

.text-bold{
  font-weight:bold;
}

.text-italic{
  font-style:italic;
}
```

And third and better, make a directive

```
<div bold-me-up="someFlag">Or even better with a directive</div>

.directive('boldMeUp', function(){
  return {
        template: '<div ng-class="{\'text-bold\' : boldMeUp, \'text-italic\' : !boldMeUp}" ng-transclude></div>',
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            boldMeUp: '='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
   };
})
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SMNX9FqvKVd5Qu5cG5gL?p=preview)

And to answer your comment, I don't think there's a way to create tag with mustache syntax it's just not the way it has been designed, [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (the thing between curly braces) are basically calls to controller and [controllers shouldn't be used to manipulate DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: I agree, controllers should not manipulate DOM, but what about `ABC and <strong>all its history</strong> will be deleted`? There should be some way semantically to talk about rich text. Lol, maybe a Markdown filter.